# Is SDL_Delay() thread safe?

Tags: c++, pthreads, sdl

I have been working on a C++ project that uses SDL, and wonder if it is safe to call SDL_Delay concurrently from different threads or if I need to write a wrapper to serialize access to the function. I rather avoid any overhead, as the delays I need are very small.

Has anyone have tried this?

I am using c++ on OS X and pthreads, and need the code to be portable.

Comment: You are asking if it is thread-safe on *all* platforms you intend to port to.  Well, probably, but expecting us to read your mind is unreasonable.

Comment: The point on using SDL is that is portable. Otherwise, I would use the SDK and/or libraries that come with my OS of choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have any direct experience with SDL_Delay but according to:  [this documentation](http://osdl.sourceforge.net/main/documentation/rendering/SDL-threads.html) it is not thread safe and you should probably use a wrapper.

Comment: Thank you. Since I was also using pthreads, I've decided to use nanosleep() instead.

Comment: @Holtorf The last update for this "documentation" was in 2006. It is not official documentation (if only for the OSDL project, and not libSDL). The best way to tell if something is thread-safe or not is to look at its source code, and SDL_Delay *is* thread-safe.